# Why is my BMI calculator showing the wrong BMI?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a BMI calculator. It was working fine until yesterday, but then it stopped showing the correct BMI. I am pretty sure all of my document.getElementById's are correct. I tried searching it up on google, but couldn't find anything.

```js
function convert() {
  var ft = document.getElementById("feetInput").value;
  var ftInches = ft * 12;
  var ftInchesSq = ftInches * ftInches;
  var inches = document.getElementById("inchInput").value;
  var inchesSq = inches * inches;
  var heightSquared = inchesSq + ftInchesSq;
  var pounds = document.getElementById("lbsInput").value;
  var bmi1 = pounds / heightSquared;
  var bmi2 = bmi1 * 703;
  var bmi = bmi2.toFixed(2);
  if (bmi < 18.5) {
    document.getElementById("outputBox").value = bmi + " - Underweight";
  }
  if (bmi > 18.51 && bmi < 24.99) {
    document.getElementById("outputBox").value = bmi + " - Normal weight";
  }
  if (bmi > 25 && bmi < 29.99) {
    document.getElementById("outputBox").value = bmi + " - Pre-obesity";
  }
  if (bmi > 30 && bmi < 34.99) {
    document.getElementById("outputBox").value = bmi + " - Obesity class 1";
  }
  if (bmi > 35 && bmi < 39.99) {
    document.getElementById("outputBox").value = bmi + " - Obesity class 2";
  }
  if (bmi >= 40) {
    document.getElementById("outputBox").value = bmi + " - Obesity class 3";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|Bungee+Shade|Covered+By+Your+Grace" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="page">
  <header>
    <h1> BMI Calculator </h1>
  </header>
  <span> <u> Enter your height and weight </u> </span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="feetInput"> &nbsp;
  <span id="feet"> Feet </span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="inchInput"> &nbsp;
  <span id="inch"> Inch </span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="lbsInput"> &nbsp;
  <span id="lbs"> Pounds </span>
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="convert()"> Calculate </button>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="outputBox" name="outputBoxName" disabled="disabled">
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to have included (a very old version of) jQuery, yet I don't see it being used at all. It would be helpful as well if you provided some test values. Also, have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: @j08691 what do you mean? What do you not see being used? And yes, I have!

Comment: Oh yes I see I'm not using jquery thank you. I will delete that html line now.

Comment: I found what is wrong. Javascript was getting the input from the inches as strings. For example, if someone is 5'6", it will add 60" + 6", but instead of getting 66" as it should, it got 606". I understand now. I figured it out by using the console.log method.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably these bits here:

```
case (b > 18.51 && b < 24.99)
```

I notice theres several of them in your code and your syntax is wrong.

The above should read:

```
case ( (b > 18.51) && (b < 24.99) )
```

since what youve actually written is equivalent to ((b > (18.51 && b)) < 24.99) which will always return "true" since (b > (18.51 && b))  will resolve to 0 or 1 which is always less than 24.99.

**Change the syntax for the case statements.**

Comment: This is not the case. Please review: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence Yes you can wrap the two statements, yet it is not necessary as `>` and `<` have higher precedence than `&&` operator. Example: `3 > 2 && 2 > 1 // returns true`

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following jQuery example. With JavaScript, you can still do the same.

```js
$(function() {
  function convert(f, i, p) {
    var ftInches = f * 12;
    var ftInchesSq = ftInches * ftInches;
    var inchesSq = i * i;
    var heightSquared = inchesSq + ftInchesSq;
    var bmi1 = p / heightSquared;
    var bmi2 = bmi1 * 703;
    return bmi2.toFixed(2);
  }

  function classify(b) {
    var rVal = b;
    switch (true) {
      case (b < 18.5):
        rVal += " - Underweight";
        break;
      case (b > 18.51 && b < 24.99):
        rVal += " - Normal weight";
        break;
      case (b > 25 && b < 29.99):
        rVal += " - Pre-obesity";
        break;
      case (b > 30 && b < 34.99):
        rVal += " - Obesity class 1";
        break;
      case (b > 35 && b < 39.99):
        rVal += " - Obesity class 2";
        break;
      case (b >= 40):
        rVal += " - Obesity class 3";
        break;
    };
    return rVal;
  }

  $("button").click(function() {
    var bmi = convert(parseInt($("#feetInput").val()), parseInt($("#inchInput").val()), parseInt($("#lbsInput").val()));
    $("#outputBox").val(classify(bmi));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|Bungee+Shade|Covered+By+Your+Grace" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="page">
  <header>
    <h1> BMI Calculator </h1>
  </header>
  <span> <u> Enter your height and weight </u> </span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="feetInput"> &nbsp;
  <span id="feet"> Feet </span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="inchInput"> &nbsp;
  <span id="inch"> Inch </span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="lbsInput"> &nbsp;
  <span id="lbs"> Pounds </span>
  <br><br>
  <button> Calculate </button>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="outputBox" name="outputBoxName" disabled="disabled">
  <br>
</div>
```

Break the steps down into easy to use functions. Input Values are always String, so best to convert them to Integer when using Math.